# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute ' - Django ORM issue

Tags: django, orm

I have 3 models 
Material, UOM, BIN_UOM

```
    @with_author  
    class Material(models.Model):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        materialuom = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                  choices=UOM_CHOICES)
        creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
        itemgroup = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
        valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        min_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
        trigger_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
        max_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)

    @with_author 
    class UOM(models.Model):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        code = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
        material =  models.ForeignKey(Material) 
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)



@with_author 
class UOM_BINUOM(models.Model):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    UOM =  models.ForeignKey(UOM) 
    BIN_UOM =  models.ForeignKey(BIN_UOM) 
    quantityperunit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
```

On the input I have my material ID

Using django ORM I want to get all the objects of  UOM_BINUOM of my material id.

In SQL :

```
 Select * from UOM_BINUOM where UOM_BINUOM.uom in (Select uom from UOM where UOM.material = material)
```

In ORM I am trying to it like this:

```
uombinuom = UOM.objects.filter(material__in=material_id).uom_binuom_set.all().order_by('-id')
```

or like this

```
    material = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=material_id)
    uom = material.uom_set.all().order_by('-id')
    uombinuom = uom.uom_binuom_set.all().order_by('-id')
```

but getting error

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'uom_binuom_set'

What I am doing wrong and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is `material_id` a list of ids, or a single id?

Comment: material_id is single id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uom_binuom_set` is for a single `UOM` instance

```
UOM.objects.get(pk=1).uom_binuom_set.all()
```

However, you have `UOM_BINUOM.objects.filter(...)`, which is a queryset. As the error says, the queryset does not have the `uom_binuom_set` method.

You can construct the queryset you want by starting with the `UOM_BINUOM` model.

```
uombinuom = UOM_BINUOM.objects.filter(UOM__material=material_id)
```

Note that since `material_id` is a single id, you don't need to use `__in`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
uom = material.uom_set.all().order_by('-id')
```

`uom` is a `QuerySet` here. `uom_binuom_set` should be called on single record not QuerySet of records.
So you will need to iterate over the `uom` QuerySet and call `.uom_binuom_set.all()` for each record.

```
for record in uom:
   uom_binuom =  record.uom_binuom_set.all()
   # do something with uom_binuom
```

Or if you want only first records related `uom_binuom` then

```
uom_binuom = uom.first().uom_binuom_set.all()
```